# Angular 2 - Приложение для пользователей с разными ролями

Tags: авторизация, angular2, frontend

Всем привет! Я новичок в мире фронтенда, поэтому просьба строго не судить.
Предстоит разработать приложение на Angular 2, внешний вид которого будет зависеть от роли пользователя.

Допустим, есть справочник с некими объектами.

Для пользователя с ролью *Админ*, должны быть доступны 2 кнопки напротив каждой записи: редактировать, удалить.

Для пользователя с ролью *Редактор*, должна быть доступна 1 кнопка напротив каждой записи: редактировать.

Для пользователя с ролью *Читатель* не должно быть доступно никаких кнопок для модификации или удаления записей справочника.

Соответственно вопрос – как лучше всего это реализовать?

У меня есть такая идея: Пользователь авторизуется, вызывая метод POST `/login`, при этом в ответе ему возвращаются права на все типы объектов приложения, к которым у него есть доступ:

для админа вернется с сервера:

```
[{"someDictionary" : {"read" : "true", "update" : "true", "delete" : "true"} }]
```

для редактора вернется с сервера:

```
[{"someDictionary" : {"read" : "true", "update" : "true" } }]
```

для читателя вернется с сервера:

```
[{"someDictionary" : {"read" : "true", "update" : "true", "delete" : "true"} }]
```

Далее, на основании полученного массива прав пользователя показываем или скрываем ему компоненты на UI (+ конечно проверки на бэкенде).

Из описанного выше варианта, я вижу такие минусы

1. В случае смены прав, пользователь сможет воспользоваться новыми правами только после перелогина.
2. Чувствую, что изобретаю велосипед.

Есть ли более правильный способ реализовать то, что описано выше? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Все гораздо проще. Нужно создать одтельные модули для разных типов юзеров и в них разные компоненты с разными кнопками и тд. При переходах на роуты нужно использовать guards на основе ролей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как по мне самый простой вариант: в бд для каждого пользователя будет поле с его правами(например админ-1 читатель -2 редактор -3) после логирования получаешь это значение и в зависимости от этого значения отображается нужный интерфейс(проверку ставить *ngIf or swichCase в темплейте)

Comment: Так в итоге и сделал, как посоветовал Александр Лонский. Спасибо!